# I have React Hook Form With Controller With Yup as validataro The Material UI Select stays red after selecting something and won't go away

Tags: material-ui, react-hook-form

I got TextField to work, now the Material UI Select will turn red if no selection is made but stays red after selection is made and won't let form submit. I'm using Yup as validation library.Maybe I keep using wrong Yup type I try String and array but I can't get it to work.

```
import {
  makeStyles,
  Box,
  Select,
  FormControl,
  InputLabel,
  MenuItem,
  Typography,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import * as yup from 'yup';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers'
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

const FormFields = ({ typeOfInquiry, typeOfProviderSupplier, feedbackform }) => {
 
  const schema = yup.object().shape({
   
   typeofInquiry: yup.array().nullable().required(),
  
  });
  const { handleSubmit, control, reset, errors } = useForm();

  return (
   
       <Controller
                  style={{ minWidth: 220 }}
                  name="typeofInquiry"
                  render ={({ field: {  ...field }, fieldState })=>{
                    console.log(props)

                 return  ( <Select  {...field} >
                     
                      {typeOfInquiry.map((person) => (
                        <MenuItem key={person.value} value={person.value} >
                          {person.label}
                        </MenuItem>
                      ))}
                    </Select>
                   )
                    }}
                  control={control}
                  defaultValue=" "

                /> 
                <Typography className={classes.red}>{errors.typeofInquiry?.message}</Typography>

              </FormControl>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to pass the `ref` to the `TextField` component.

Here is a working example
 https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-pateu-3n0i9

You should do something similar with `Select`.
Some examples with MUI: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v7-controller-5h1q5?file=/src/Mui.js

Comment: Thank you I'm using Yup and got  TextField to work but still having problems with Select